# Return mysqli result as array

Tags: php, mysqli

How do I return the result of a mysqli query as an associative array?

I want to pass it to my view layer as an array so that I can separate the html from the model layer. It's a table so it could have unlimited rows...

```
if ($statement = $this->mysqli->db->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->store_result();
    if ($statement->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return ????????;    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

store_result should return a mysqli_result object. Use the `fetch_all` method of `mysqli_result` to get the result as associative array.

See this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

Comment: I tried fetch_all() before and it said the method didn't exist. Is there some specific way of implementing it?

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_array()

Comment: I think it is because as it is stated here[link](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) this is only available with the MySQL Native driver only. Can you try using mysqlnd?

Comment: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_all()

Comment: Oh I will try to get that driver installed ty!

Answer (score -2):

```
if ($statement = $this->mysqli->db->prepare($query))
{
    $statement->bind_param("i", $user_id);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->get_result();
    if ($statement->num_rows > 0)
    {
        return $statement->fetch_assoc();  
    }
}
```